# WordPress encoding problem

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encoding

I'm having what seems to be a problem related to WordPress, though it could be something else.

Here's what's happening:

I have a blog with posts using utf-8 characters (simple ones like ’).  The characters all display correctly currently, however I'm moving my site to another server and seeing problems with all the utf-8 chars (’ becomes â€™).

I first thought the problem was with MySQL, but after looking into it it seems not to be the case.  I created the new database by doing a synch with Navicat, and have confirmed that both db's and all tables are utf-8.  When viewing the data in either db in any SQL program I've tried (Sequel Pro, Navicat) the chars show up unencoded (â€™).  I've tried various synching methods, including ones that others have said solved encoding problems, but they did not work for me.

What confirmed it for me, was setting up a test php script which pulled a single post_content field from each database. In the test script the chars show up encoded (’) regardless of which db they come from.

I checked the apache config file and found that HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET is set to the same (ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7) on both systems.

Soooo, I'm left thinking that it's a WordPress issue, though of course I could be wrong.

Any help would be truly appreciated, Iâ€™ve been banging my head on this for awhile now ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've finally ended up using a plug-in to solve the problem.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Migrate the structure and content of the old database to the new database using Navicat for MySQL (though I think any method of copying will work).
2. Change the encoding of the columns in the wp_posts table to utf8 using `ALTER TABLE 'wp_posts' CHANGE COLUMN 'post_content' 'post_content' longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL after 'post_date_gmt';`
3. Use the [ISO to UTF content plug in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iso-2-utf-data-converter/) to convert any non-encoded chars innthe table to utf chars.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is UTF-8 data being interpreted as if it were ISO-8859-1 (or Win-1252, or another single-byte encoding). Problems like this are almost always a mismatch between the headers being sent to the browser and the actual encoding.  Something is telling the browser that the stream is ISO-8859-1 while actually sending UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've looked into it. Both servers are sending a header with Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8 and Transfer-Encoding chunked (in case that matters).  What else would you recommend I look for?

Comment: What browser? Also, are these blogs visible on the Internet? Can you post links?